# Themes all deactivating at irregular interval

Tags: 7

I recently updated my website from 7.22 to 7.33.

I have a problem with my templates randomly getting disabled.

I have 3 themes : desktop / mobile / corpo.

My URLs are has follow : 
www.mywebsite.com -> desktop / mobile (module mobile switcher)
www.mywebsite.com/corpo -> corpo

They both point to different databases, via settings.php places in the following folders:
/sites/mywebsite.com
/sites/mywebsite.com.corpo

The corpo theme stays activated.

The 2 others often get deactivated (I tried clearing the cache, before anyone suggests that :) ). If I want to reactivate them, I click on "Enable" .

If I click on "enable and set as default", it's the default Garland theme that gets set.

Let me know if I can provide more info on this!

Thanks,

Comment: hmmm given the cache clearing isn't working my first thought is that your website my be totally broken. Specifically I'm wondering how recently you updated from 7.22 because if it was after October you may have a hacked/damaged site: https://www.drupal.org/PSA-2014-003.